# prefetch_related and Prefetch object issue, filtering thru reverse Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models, company and Product.

```
class Product(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

form the database I'm trying to get the Company data and the corresponding products.

From the products I want to get only the name and to be ordered descending by updated_at, created_at.

I'm working with `Prefetch` object and `prefetch_related` and definitively I have multiple misunderstandings how they work.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Company.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.only('name').order_by('-updated_at', '-created_at'))).get()
    return qs
```

The error that I receive is:

```
get() returned more than one Company
```

Because I closed the `prefetch_related` method/function with `)))` :

1. I thought `get()` will act over the Company object and get it using the pk/slug from the url(as get do by default in DetailView). Seems that is not the case.
2. I'm already using 'products' the related name in the Prefetch object, why in queryset is necessary to tell again the model `queryset=Product.objects....` ?

I was looking at the following example in django documentation:

```
   Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('choice_set')).get().choice_set.all()
```

If there is 'choice_set' in `Prefetch` object why is called at the end `choice_set.all()` ?

Isn't Django attached to the quesryset in prefetch_related the products to the queryset (question.choice_set) ?

I think my problem is that I don't understand the order of execution, and I'm confused how methods are chained, even if are closed by ')'

Comment: @Alasdair - docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch (see Prefetch Object)

Comment: I think it would be better if the examples in the docs didn't use `get()` - it's potentially confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryset.get()` will only work if the queryset has a single object. If it contains zero or more than one objects, you'll get an error.

You should return a queryset from the `get_queryset` object. In the class based view, the code that filters on the pk/slug is in `get_object`.

The `prefetch_related` method is useful if you want to fetch the products for multiple countries. The way that the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) use `get()` is confusing in my opinion - if the queryset has a single item then `prefetch_related` is over-complicated.

If you have a single company, then there is no advantage, and the code will be simpler if you fetch the countries separately, e.g. in `get_context_data`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['products'] = Product.objects.filter(company=self.object).Product.objects.only('name').order_by('-updated_at', '-created_at')))
    return context
```

I've removed the `only('name')` call. It's an optimisation that you probably don't need.

If you really want to use `prefetch_related`, then remove the `get()`.

```
qs = Company.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('products', queryset=Product.objects.order_by('-updated_at', '-created_at')))
```

By specifying the queryset above, you are able to change the order (you could filter it if you like). If you don't want to customize the queryset you can simply do:

```
Company.objects.prefetch_related('products')
```

When you use `Question.objects.prefetch_related(...)`, the queryset is still a list of questions. You need to call `choice_set.all()` on the individual instances to access their choices. This won't cause any additional queries, because Django has already prefetched the choices.

```
queryset = Question.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('choice_set'))
for question in queryset:
    print(question) # the question
    print(question.choice_set.all())  # the related choices
```

Comment: thanks, but I still want to understand how Prefetch object is working , and how can be used, instead of using separate context key